# Rust global variable referencing non global variable

Tags: rust

I using a Windows API that does not support callbacks. Thus, I need to create a global to enable the Windows API to call back my code.

I have the following code, that works. [rust play ground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2adcfadd6550a89acac80b721a14cb2)

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct MyGlobal<'a> {
    my_local: Option<&'a MyLocal>
}

impl<'a> MyGlobal<'a> {
    fn print(&self) {
        match &self.my_local {
            Some(my_local) => my_local.print(),
            None => ()
        }
    }
}

struct MyLocal {}

impl MyLocal {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let my_local = Self {};
        
        let my_global = MyGlobal { my_local: Some(&my_local) };
        my_global.print();
        my_local
    }
    
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("Called");
    }
}

static MY_GLOBAL: Mutex<MyGlobal> = Mutex::new(MyGlobal { my_local: None });

fn main() {
    MyLocal::new();
}
```

What I need is to transform the `my_global` variable into a global, such as a static variable or a singleton.

If I change the line:

```rust
let my_global = MyGlobal { my_local: Some(&my_local) };
```

per: [rust play ground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4c155096fc8d3a416b10beb9ca25d08)

```rust
MY_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap().my_local = Some(&my_local);
let my_global = MY_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap();
```

I start to get the error "`my_local` does not live long enough".

How can I achieve a global variable in rust?

I found other related questions regarding global variables and rust, but as far as I searched, most of them only use primitive types. The problem I am facing is regarding the diferent lifetimes of the static MY_GLOBAL and the my_local.

Comment: Globals cannot reference locals, full stop. As soon as the local stops existing, the global would contain an orphaned reference. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What's your actual goal with this code?

Comment: Thank you. The problem, as stated in the first paragraph is that I am using a Windows API that does not support callbacks. Thus, I need to create a global to enable the Windows API to call back my code.

Comment: But `&my_local` is a reference to a **local** which is **imposssible** to store in a `static`, store the value instead! Please add your actual problem like cdhowie asked you to.

Comment: Which Windows API are you trying to use? I assume you have to pass a pointer to your variable in it - what does it to with the variable, does it write to it?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use `Arc` here instead of a bare reference.

Comment: Can you provide an example using `Arc`?

Comment: The API is the SetWinEventHook, but the question is regarding using globals. I believe I can use the API with a Sender